# R: Iterate over columns and calculate the error rate

Tags: r, dataframe

I have build 10 Models and generate their predictions as follows:

```
      M1       M2       M3        M4      M5         M6       M7       M8     M9        M10 
1  9.546223 8.713140 8.736672 8.711169 8.719074  8.696506 8.849216 8.685843 8.720186 8.707842 
2  9.333491 8.633371 8.703537 8.659186 8.652638  8.651705 8.685260 8.651955 8.665795 8.660157 
3 10.134578 8.621685 8.707592 8.657538 8.646744  8.660359 8.723335 8.659033 8.666371 8.659188 
4 11.693361 8.606719 8.702254 8.637670 8.627075  8.596533 8.727353 8.610436 8.662495 8.636437
```

I want to iterate column by column and calculate the RMSE, I tried following but it prints the same value:

```
for(i in names(df)) {
  x = df$i
  print(sqrt(mean((x-test$value)^2)))

}
```

Whats the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: does `x = df[[i]]` instead of `x = df$i` work

Comment: There is also a package called `Metrics` that has functions such as `RMSE`, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use a `for` loop. If you want to perform the same operation for each column of a data frame, use `lapply`.

```
RMSE <- function (x, test) sqrt(mean((x-test$value)^2))
x <- lapply(df, FUN = RMSE, test)
```

By default, `lapply` returns a list.

If you want a data frame, do `as.data.frame(x)`;

If you want a vector, do `unlist(x)`.

Comment: great, if I want to do dump result into df such as `c(modelName, RMSE)` how hard is that?

Comment: this is what i did `new_df <- as.data.frame(unlist(lapply(df, FUN = RMSE, test)), col.names=c("c","d"))` but the index has model name